# How to mount disc from RAID 1 OS 10.11.6?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, mount

My NAS RAID 1  disappear :/
Crappy Unitek Y-3357

I think that one drive is healthy but ...is there any way to mount the disc and recover data ?

[image]

Comment: it is going to depend heavily on what disk format it is. From your screen capture it looks like there are no mountable filesystems. You may need to ask their tech support what filesystem they use, otherwise you should be able to buy a comparable HD, stick it in the NAS and let the RAID rebuild itself.

Comment: Just to re-iterate:  [RAID is not backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037143/why-is-raid-1-considered-bad-for-backup)  If you don't already have a backup strategy in place, this is a good wake up call to do so.

Comment: @SteveChambers -  comparable HD means - same exactly,  or just same
capacity. I just send to the a question about the file system...

Comment: @Allan. now i know :/

Comment: What @SteveChambers said is spot on.  You should be able to add another drive to the array and it will rebuild itself unless of course, the array itself went south.  You may also want to explore the possibility of using commercial software to recover it.  RAID 1 being a mirror, you have a higher chance of recover than say a RAID 0 or RAID 5  See:  https://www.cleverfiles.com/help/raid-recovery/

Comment: Roughly the same capacity, but if you cant get one that is bigger and the RAID will ignore the extra space on the other drive. Other than that the make and model don't matter, unless the RAID manufacturer has put some deliberate limitations on their products.